# DLL load failed while importing _imaging on clean anaconda install

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library, conda, conda-forge

I installed anaconda for the first time and have had to uninstall and reinstall many times due to different issues I've faced. This is my first time working with the program so I don't know much about it.

On a clean install I entered the following into the anaconda prompt:

```
conda update --all
conda install pyreadstat --channel conda-forge --yes
conda install geopandas --channel conda-forge
```

Then, when launching Jupyter and running the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
```

I receive the following error:

```
if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
            msg = (
              "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
              f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
              f"Pillow version: {__version__}"
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

When running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
poll_url = 'http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/general-model/president_general_polls_2016.csv'
polls = pd.read_csv(poll_url)
polls

polls.sort_values('startdate', ascending=False, inplace=True)
polls.head()

polls.drop(columns=['cycle','branch','matchup','forecastdate'], inplace=True)
polls.head(2)

polls.plot.line(xlim=('2016-06','2016-11'))
```

I receive the error:

```
ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.
```

I had trouble installing geopandas for several days and would get stuck in solving environment for hours at a time and a few times my navigator wouldn't open after.

Installation instructions are from the Murach book Data Analysis for Python, and the code shown above is as well. I'm assuming there's some kind of compatibility error somewhere? Solutions I've seen are to use pip, which can corrupt your environment when mixed with conda commands, or creating a separate environment, but the book requires you to work in the base. Some of the packages and versions I have are:

```
conda 23.7.3
geopandas 0.13.2
ipython 8.12.2
matplotlib 3.7.1
pandas 2.0.3
pillow 9.4.0
python 3.11.4
```

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is searching for an answer to this, I ended up just making a new env and never got it figured out why it wouldn't work on the base.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same error somedays ago after installing `geopandas` some day ago. My python version is `3.10.12`. I solved this by doing the following steps:

Downgraded my `pillow` package to version-9.0.0. It is working fine since then.
Just do this:

```
conda remove pillow
```

then install `pillow-9.0.0` with pip:

```
pip install pillow==9.0.0
```

I don't know the exact reason for the conflict between `matplotlib` and `pillow` but downgrading it worked for me. Also I found the solutio from here: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/11103

###### Edit: How to create a new conda environment with specific python version

Choose the python version you want. Then activate the environment.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.10
```

```
conda activate myenv
```

Comment: I got an error " Pillow 9.0.0 does not support Python 3.11 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries". How would I downgrade my python version? Also, does using pip to install when I've been using conda make my enviorment unstable?

Comment: Using conda install python=3.10.0 gives a bunch of package incompatibilities

Comment: Nah your environment wont be unstable. Also for downgrading python, uninstall the existing conda and download the python3.10 version from here https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda-other-installer-links.html. then install it

Comment: "RemoveError: This operation will remove conda without replacing it with another version of conda." How should I go about removing conda? Also that is for miniconda, is that the same as just conda?

Comment: Miniconda and Anaconda are different. See here for more https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/download.html#anaconda-or-miniconda. But miniconda is sufficient with minimal packages

Comment: wait, you don't have to downgrade to python3.10 if are not comfortable, you can just create a new conda enironment with python 3.10 and then install the packages there

Comment: I don't think I can do it in a new enviornment. I'm following the Murach book instructions for a class for school :/ That's part of the issue.

Comment: okay then, during which command did you faced the error?

Comment: "conda uninstall conda"

Comment: no no, don't do it like that. follow the instructions here: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/#full-uninstall

Comment: I have everything installed, how do I install the navigator? using 'conda install anaconda-navigator" gives error "ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - conda==23.5.2". Conda version is 23.7.3

Comment: Looks like you need a older conda version, here you can find `conda23.5.2` https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda/files?page=3

Comment: How do I install it? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: you can download a specific package version from there. Or run `conda install -c anaconda conda=23.5.2`

Comment: Gave me a bunch of errors for incompatible packages. I really just need it to be fixed in regular anaconda for school.

Comment: you're clearly new, so I really advice you that just keep the original conda that you installed, then create a new environment with python3.10. install all your packages on that environment. That's really the best approach